# Does "Calendar.current.isDate" date parameter need to use the date in the same timezone?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, timezone

I have a question about `Calendar.current.isDate` this function.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
print("locale   : \(calendar.locale)")    //Optional(en_US (current))
print("timeZone : \(calendar.timeZone)")  //Asia/Taipei (current) UCT+8

if calendar.isDate(latestDate, inSameDayAs: nowDate) {
    // latestDate = 2019-08-08 03:17:56 +0000
    // nowDate = 2019-08-08 03:47:43 +0000
    // Doing something
}
```

I take two date parameters `latestDate` and `nowDate`, but  these two parameters timezone is UCT+0.
And my calendar timezone is UCT+8.

Is this legal to compare they are the same day in spite of different timezone?

Comment: *"but these two parameters timezone is UCT+0"* - no they are not. `Date` has no timezone. Don't be misled by the default output of printing `Date` instances being shown in the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date`s don't have a timezone.  They are an absolute point in time.  When you print the date, the system has to use some timezone to provide context to the value displayed and it uses UTC+0, but  2019-08-08 03:17:56 +0000 and  2019-08-08 11:17:56 +0800 *are the same time*

Your `calendar` instance will interpret both of the `Date`s in its timezone.

So your `if` will be `true` if both of those `Date`s are in the same day in the calendar's timezone (The current device timezone in the case of your code).

Comment: If you mean "will it give the right result", the answer is "Yes"

Comment: It will give the correct result if your goal is to compare the two dates in the user's current timezone (the default used by `Calendar.current`).

Comment: Fun fact: The two specific dates shown in the question can only be in two different days in the UTC-3:30 timezone. In that timezone, the first date would be 2019-08-07 23:47:56 and the second would be 2019-08-08 00:17:43. So only the people in Newfoundland and Labrador, Canada would see those two as different days.